How do I enable TLS with Prometheus?
I'm running prometheus 2.53.0 on RHEL 8.10.
All working fine until I want to enable TLS.
This is my prometheus.yml file:
# my global config
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s # Set the scrape interval to every 15 seconds. Default is every 1 minute.
  evaluation_interval: 15s # Evaluate rules every 15 seconds. The default is every 1 minute.
   # scrape_timeout is set to the global default (10s).

# Alertmanager configuration
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
    - static_configs:
      - targets:
        # - alertmanager:9093

# Load rules once and periodically evaluate them according to the global 'evaluation_interval'.
rule_files:
  # - "first_rules.yml"
  # - "second_rules.yml"

# A scrape configuration containing exactly one endpoint to scrape:
# Here it's Prometheus itself.
scrape_configs:
  # The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.
  - job_name: "prometheus"

  # metrics_path defaults to '/metrics'
  # scheme defaults to 'http'.

  static_configs:
    - targets: ["localhost:9090"]

  - job_name: "node"
    scheme: https
    tls_config:
      cert_file: "/etc/prometheus/node_exporter.crt"
      key_file: "/etc/prometheus/node_exporter.key"
      insecure_skip_verify: true
    static_configs:
      - targets: ["anotherserver:9100"]

I have tried several combinations under tls_config, but when I look in /var/log/messages, I always see:
level=info component=web msg="TLS is disabled." http2=false address=[::]:9090

I've been looking at many example configs found on the internet, and I see no issues with my config.
What am I doing wrong here ?

First, this is probably a wrong place to ask about configurations.

Second, in your config - I don't see you trying to configure tlsof your Prometheus instance. Only scraping of anotherserver using https.
